# Backup a folder to pemdrive from GTK application

Tags: gtk, usb, udev, mount-point

I am using GTK+3 for my application running on Toradex SOM. I need to allow the user to take a backup of a folder in /home/root/folder to USB that is being inserted on a button click. For this the location of source file is always same. But I when take pendrive location as /media/sda1, it is changing dynamically with removal and insertion. So I am not able to hard code the destination pendrive location like for source folder. I tried udev and with that I can get device node name when inserted but not the mount point of the USB. What is the exact way of handling this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the proposed solution here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/766506/automount-usb-drives-with-systemd

May suit your need.

Best regards,
André Curvello